# Stubbing/mocking/spying methods of target test class

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I need to test a method in a angular class. This method invokes another method in same class, so I need to stub/mock that invoked method.

I tried spyOn with callFake, but that doesn't work.

Whats the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

jasmine.createSpy worked for me.